# How to Validate Token JWT Token that it comes from the same User in Web API C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

Recently built JWT token using web API Core. Just need serious clarification below are the details

If User A is logged using browser tab A and request has been processed and token is generated. If  User B is logged using browser tab B and request has been processed and token is generated. What will happen if i sent User A token to User B  How to validate the token that this token is for this particular logged in user ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be misunderstanding the way Authentication work generally.

In JWT Auth, 'logged in' simply means that the request you're making contains a valid Bearer token. This means that the user that sends a valid token is always the valid logged-in user and there is no need for any further validation.

If however, you need further information based on the Authenticated user, you can access that information from the `HttpContext` or the `ClaimsPrincipal` property in your controller named `User`.

For example,

```
string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Bearer", "access_token");
string userName = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
```

NB: You must explicitly store claims that you'd love to retrieve from the `User` property.

Comment: Yes I understand. My Question is what happen if sent a different valid token. Suppose you logged in one tab and i in another tab same computer what will happen if the hacker uses my token instead of your token for another request . My Point is how to validate that Manoj token is manoj token and smart E token is smart E token?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you are saying better. In your controller, the ``User`` property contains information that you have stored in the access token like userId, username etc. I'll update my answer to reflect these

Comment: Thanks. I will check and accept answer. Just started to learning JWT

Comment: Still it is confusing . Because even-though we can get the userID from claims which we attached. Is that we can validate that the token is requested by same person (e-g) if i used smartE token from manoj request again it is going to get the userid of smart and it is valid token is that correct?